# Primary user won't run Firefox 4 after upgrade to Natty

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I just upgraded from Maverick to Natty. My main account still runs Firefox 3.6. However, I know that Firefox 4 is installed, because I created a new user and it runs Firefox 4.

How do I get my main user account to run Firefox 4 from Unity?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about not adding my solution. I tried several times, but I was fighting with the stupid captcha applet.

Anyway, I discovered that there was an old, manually installed Firefox 3.6 in /opt/firefox. This is what the icon was trying to start. I deleted that folder, then the icon wouldn't start anything.

So, I uninstalled and reinstalled FF 4 using aptitude. Then, I found that I could start FF 4 from the terminal, but the icon was still looking for /opt/firefox.

I could not find out how to fix that in Unity, so I logged into Gnome Classic and changed the Properties of both the icon and the menu item for Firefox. Then, when I logged back into Unity, the icon worked.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

**First method**

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `system`, click on `System Settings` -> `Personal section` -> `Preferred Applications` -> `Internet tab` -> `Web Browser`, choose `Firefox Web Browser`.

**Second method**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `firefox`, hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, from menu `Edit` -> `Preferences`, `Advanced` -> `General Tab` -> `System Defaults`, click on `Check Now`, click on `Yes`, click on `Close`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Vanni, but I tried it both ways you gave, and my primary user still runs FF 3.6.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I don't know if it was the best way, but it worked.

Comment: @`Tim`: what was your solution?